# Multiple objects in list, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I'm looking for something similar to `List<T>`, that would allow me to have multiple `T`. For example: `List<TabItem, DataGrid, int, string, ...> = new List<TabItem, DataGrid, int, string, ...>()`.

Comment: Do you want a generic List that can store any of those types... or do you want a generic List that can store a grouping of those types (that is, each element is an associated TabItem, DataGrid, int, string, etc)?

Comment: and ideally ... how would you use or consume this list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4, you could have a `List<Tuple<T1, T2, ...>>`

Otherwise, your choice is to implement your own type.

Comment: You got this in as I was typing my answer.

Comment: It don't need List<Tuple<T1, T2, ...>>, just Tuple<T1,T2> is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Create a class that defines your data structure, and then do

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
```

Comment: structure would be better than class.

Comment: @Harsha: If you are going to make this statement, at least give us a reason why.

Comment: hi, here is the link which says that structures are better than class but only when they contain little data.

here is the link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/6923cbe6-12b7-4e97-a4f5-3d9ebdfc75f2

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd just have `List<MyClass>` where `MyClass` had all those other ones as members.

Answer (score 1):

If it can have any old type, then you need to use an ArrayList.

If you know ahead of time what you'll have in there, then you should either create your own structure, or use a Tuple.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're after `List<object>`?

Answer (score -1):

Tuples are best if you are using .net 4.0. But if you are working 3.5 or below, multidimensional object array is good. Here is the code. I have added 3 different types in a object array and I pushed the same to list. May not be the best solution for your question, can be achieved with object array and list. Take a look at the code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[,] OneObject = new object[1,3]{ {"C Sharp",4,3.5 }};
        List<object> MyList = new List<object>();
        MyList.Add(OneObject);
        object[,] addObject = new object[1,3]{{"Java",1,1.1}};
        MyList.Add(addObject);

        foreach(object SingleObject in MyList)
        {
            object[,] MyObject = (object[,])SingleObject;

            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", MyObject[0, 0], MyObject[0, 1], MyObject[0, 2]);
        }  

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of trying in C# 4, you can give the old version features a chance here.

It seems you don't need a strongly typed collection here, in that case ArrayList is the best option.